# Segmentation fault в релизе

Tags: g++, segmentation-fault

Собираю релиз программы под линукс, при запуске получаю Segmentation fault. В дебаге все работает нормально.

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) Только что поставил.

Исследование показало, что падает на этой функции

```
MString AESDecode(VString line, VString ckey, VString ivec){
    MString ret;
    ret.Reserv(line.sz+16);
    int retlen=0, retlenf=0;

    if(!ckey || !ivec)
        return MString();

// print("DEC: ", itos(line.sz), ".\r\n"); // not fault
// printf("%d", line.sz); // fault
// printf("%d", ret.sz); // fault
// itos(line.sz); // not fault
// itos(0); // not fault
// void * v = malloc(1); // fault      

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_DecryptInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), ckey, ivec);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, ret, &retlen, line, line);
    EVP_DecryptFinal(&ctx, ret.data+retlen, &retlenf);

    ret.Reserv(retlen+retlenf);
    return ret;
}
```

падает на `EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, ret, &retlen, line, line);`

class MString и class VString состоят из unsigned char *data; unsigned int sz;

MString itos(int) - возвращает буфер с текстовым представлением числа.

Насколько я вижу, g++ слишком сильно оптимизировал код, в результате чего происходит падение программы. Если ему помешать, падения прекращаются.

Что компилятор меняет, вызывая падение программы? Я так понимаю он меняет последовательность выполнения, хотелось бы понять, что именно и почему.

Как переписать код, чтобы падения прекратились?

Comment: Хоть скажите, что за библиотечные функции, что они делают. И попробуйте локализовать еще точнее: например, откомпилируйте с отладочной информацией *и* с вашим флагом оптимизации и посмотрите в дебаггере, где точно падает

Comment: Это функции из библиотеки openssl. Во, line и ivec = <value optimized out>, а ret.data = 0. То есть компилятор решил не вызывать первый ret.Reserv(), в котором выделяется память и в функцию передается 0, вместо указателя на нормальный буфер, что и вызывает падение. Теперь бы понять, чем это лечить.

Comment: Проверьте, что правда ноль, я как-то сомневаюсь, что компилятор такой тупой. Также приведите определения своих классов, может в них проблема.

Comment: В отладчике показывает 0. Добавил в код проверку через if, пишет, что указатель не нулевой.  Завтра вытащу эту функцию из проекта, в минимальном исполнении.

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось хитрее. Удалось, путем закомментирования кода, определить проблемный файл. Причина проблемы: #pragma pack(push,4) и отсутствие закрывающего #pragma pack(pop);

Comment: Кстати, самый хороший метод отладки «невозможных» багов.